# Run java in terminal with and without arguments at same time

Tags: java, terminal

I have pw_check.java and I need to run it with an argument first and then run it without argument in terminal.

> java pw_check -g
>
> java pw_check

But in second command, without argument, the system is throwing exception. How could I handle it to feed my requirement.

Comment: what exception u r getting, while u r running ur program without argument?

Comment: With argument, the main method will generate all good passwords. Then without argument, it will let user to input password and check whether it is good or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the code pw_check.java.

Probably there is something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Code accessing args[0]

}
```

This will cause an error if you don't have a parameter.

Modify with a code similar to the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String arg = DEFAULT_ARG;
    if (args.length == 1) {
        arg = args[0];
    }
    ... // Code using arg DEFAULT or passed value
}
```

Comment: If you think that this answer was useful you can upvote it and flag it as the right answer with the green check. Thank you